# TableLayout filled programatically wont show in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablelayout

TRYING: to start with an empty table-layout and then grow it dynamically with rows.

PROBLEM: I don't see anything. I have checked, the `onCreateView` does get called but still nothing shows.

NOTE: I am using fragments

Fragment Class:

```
 public class PointsTableFragment extends Fragment {

    String[][] data = { 
            { "team", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", "p7" },
            { "team", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", "p7" },
            { "team", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", "p7" },
            { "team", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", "p7" },
            { "team", "p1", "p2", "p3", "p4", "p5", "p6", "p7" }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_points_table,
                container, false);

        TableLayout table = (TableLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.points_table);



        for (String[] row : data) {

            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this.getActivity());
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            for(String value : row){

                TextView tv = new TextView(this.getActivity());
                tv.setText(value);
                tv.setTextSize(18);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                tr.addView(tv);

            }   
            table.addView(tr);
        }



        return rootView;
    }
    }
```

Fragment Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fixture_list_divider"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/points_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7" >
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `LinearLayout LayoutParams` and `TableLayout LayoutParams` as a parameter not the native `ViewGroup LayoutParams`.

**change this:**

```
    tv.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

**to:**

```
    tv.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Changed it the way you said, didnt help!